# Android API: Status Bar - redirect to phone/sms/gmail/etc

Tags: java, android, notifications, statusbar

Is it possible to redirect user after clicking notification in status bar to e.g. phone/sms/gmail/.. ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the "setLatestEventInfo"- method. It looks like this in my App:

```
Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleClass.class);

        PendingIntent nManagerStart = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                msgIntent, 0);

        msg.flags |= (Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

msg.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, nManagerStart);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, msg);
```

As you see, one can add a pendingIntent to a notification.

Here is a guide for the Notification Manager: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html